# Integral change at jump discontinuity.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

[image]

The above is the graph of $f(t)$.

$q(x)$ is defined as:

$$q(x) = \int_{0}^{2x - 1} f(t) dt$$

What is $q'(5/2)$ I would say it DOES NOT exist (discontinuity at $x = 4$) after Itake $q'(x)$

Comment: It does not exist, but can you not take it as piece wise continuous? and compute q accordingly? is the question to prove that for the continuous support if you can define the integral?

Comment: @Chinny84, no proof needed. I was thinkign because $f(t)$ is not cont. at $x = 4$